# How to redirect home(dashboard in my page) page if invoked login url after once logged in using spring boot security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Below is my code :

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security)throws Exception{
        security.csrf().disable();
        security
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login","/forgotpassword","/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)

            .permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a filter. The filter can config processing path(`/login`) and redirect path(`/dashboard`).

If the request path matches processing path(`/login`), then try to get `Authentication` from `SecurityContextHolder`, if the `Authentication` is not null and `anonymous`, redirect to redirect path(`dashboard`), or do nothing.

Then inject the filter to filter chain.